# Why am I getting file access denied trying to make a StreamWriter instance?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
string pathDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\settings";
string settingsFile = "settings.txt";
StreamWriter w;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(pathDir, settingsFile)))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(pathDir, settingsFile));
    settingsFile = Path.Combine(pathDir, settingsFile);
    w = new StreamWriter(settingsFile, true);
```

The exception is on the line:

```
w = new StreamWriter(settingsFile, true);
```

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Grads_Scripts\Grads_Scripts\settings\settings.txt' is denied

And now i moved the instance of the StreamWriter to a textBox1_TextChanged event:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            w = new StreamWriter(settingsFile, true);
            w.Write(textBox1.Text);
            w.Close();
        }
```

I want to write the text i type in the textBox1 in real time to the text file. Without a button click confirm or something but in real time. While i'm typing it will write it to the text file. But the way it is now i see in the text file everything i typed many times the same.

Comment: Do you have "settings.txt" open in something else, such as Notepad?

Comment: I appears you are creating a directory named `[...]\Grads_Scripts\settings\settings.txt` then trying to write to it as a file.

Comment: Good catch Ryan, to me, IMO, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appears you are creating a directory named `[...]\Grads_Scripts\settings\settings.txt` then trying to write to it as a file. Go to the directory `C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\Grads_Scripts\Grads_Scripts\settings\` and see if there is a folder called `settings.txt`.  If so, delete it and modify your code to create the parent directory only.

You should be able to change your code as follows:

```
string pathDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + "\\settings";
string settingsFile = "settings.txt";
StreamWriter w;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Create the parent directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(pathDir)) 
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDir);
    settingsFile = Path.Combine(pathDir, settingsFile);
    w = new StreamWriter(settingsFile, true);
}
```

Remember to wrap your `StreamWriter` in a using statement (or call `Dispose` manually) so that the file resources are released after you've finished writing.

```
using( w = new StreamWriter(settingsFile, true) ){
    // Write to stream writer
}
```